# Wiring a Leviton Motion Light Control

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a single pole light switch with the motion sensor.  I have two black wires, one red and ground.  The two black are connected to 1 hot and 1 neutral.  The red wire is common hot.  How do I connect the Leviton with three connections...1 black screw, one red screw and 1 ground?

Comment: Single pole double throw switch or 3 way ? The 2 blacks and common red as a hot sounds like a 3 way. Are there 3 contacts on the existing switch? + a green ground screw.

Comment: Gonna need a photo of what is in the box.  I don't think that's neutral. Is it ever hot?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes?